# Why resolveInstanceMethod: called twice sometimes

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Recently, I'm studying the runtime in Objective-C.

I created a class named `TO`:

```
@interface TO : NSObject
@end

#import "TO.h"

@implementation TO

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSLog(@"%@ sel: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSLog(@"%@ sel: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel {
    NSLog(@"%@ sel: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel {
    NSLog(@"%@ sel: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    return NO;
}

+ (IMP)instanceMethodForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSLog(@"%@ sel: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    return nil;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

@end
```

Then, I call an unrecongnized selector somewhere:

```
TO *to = [TO new];
id res = [(NSString *)to uppercaseString];
```

Subsequently, I got the following output:

```
2015-12-22 22:27:04.319 OCDemo[81920:7728539] resolveInstanceMethod: sel: uppercaseString
2015-12-22 22:27:04.320 OCDemo[81920:7728539] forwardingTargetForSelector: sel: uppercaseString
2015-12-22 22:27:04.320 OCDemo[81920:7728539] resolveInstanceMethod: sel: uppercaseString
2015-12-22 22:27:04.320 OCDemo[81920:7728539] -[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd3ad120a0
2015-12-22 22:27:04.322 OCDemo[81920:7728539] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd3ad120a0'
```

As we see, `resolveInstanceMethod:` was called twice.

However，if I call `-[description]` firstly:

```
TO *to = [TO new];
[to description];
id res = [(NSString *)to uppercaseString];
```

Then, the output would be:

```
2015-12-22 22:58:50.458 OCDemo[82137:7813436] resolveInstanceMethod: sel: uppercaseString
2015-12-22 22:58:50.459 OCDemo[82137:7813436] forwardingTargetForSelector: sel: uppercaseString
2015-12-22 22:58:50.459 OCDemo[82137:7813436] -[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9bcad59960
2015-12-22 22:58:50.461 OCDemo[82137:7813436] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9bcad59960'
```

This time `resolveInstanceMethod:` was called only once.

Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first method invocation on given class (it will be `[to description]` in your example) caches the class selectors. In effect `resolveInstanceMethod:` is called only once for unrecognized selectors.

You can see this when you flush the method cache for given class with function

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
void _objc_flush_caches(Class cls)
```

Modified example:

```
TO *to = [TO new];
[to description];
_objc_flush_caches([to class]);
id res = [(NSString *)to uppercaseString];
```

gives the following output:

```
2017-04-15 21:48:21.575527+0200 pro objective c games[29820:1116842] resolveInstanceMethod: sel: uppercaseString
2017-04-15 21:48:21.575760+0200 pro objective c games[29820:1116842] forwardingTargetForSelector: sel: uppercaseString
2017-04-15 21:48:21.575808+0200 pro objective c games[29820:1116842] resolveInstanceMethod: sel: uppercaseString
2017-04-15 21:48:21.575833+0200 pro objective c games[29820:1116842] -[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100303600
2017-04-15 21:48:21.579989+0200 pro objective c games[29820:1116842] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TO uppercaseString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100303600'
```

as you can see `resolveInstanceMethod:` is called twice, even if `[to description]` was called earlier. When you comment out `\\_objc_flush_caches([to class]);`, then `resolveInstanceMethod:` will be called once. Like in your second example. It suggests that the behavior you noticed is linked to method caching.